# Navigation anchor tags not working, but why?

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation, onepage-scroll

So I have a two page website. Home page has a one-page navigation i.e. when '*about*' is clicked it is scrolled down to the '*about*' div.

**PART 1 - On index.html**

- However when 'blog' navigation item is clicked it SHOULD go to
  blog.html. In `.header-nav` I have the following `<li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>` but isn't working. In the browser it is showing that the link is directed to blog.html but doesn't go.

**PART 2 - On Blog.html**

- On, `blog.html`, I have **copied the `.header-nav` code from index.html** - but when I click 'about' it **should go to home page and scroll down to about div -it's not!**
  Even though the code is working In the index.html page. **ANY ideas will be greatly appreciated!**

**Index.html**

```
    <header class="main-header">
        <div class="header-container">
            <!-- logo wrapper -->
            <div class="logo-wrapper">

            <div id="logo-img-name">
                <picture>
                    <source class="logo-img" media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img/mobile/mobile-logo.jpg">
<!--                  <source media="(min-width: 465px)" srcset="img_white_flower.jpg">
 -->                  <img class="logo-img" src="img_orange_flowers.jpg" alt="Flowers" style="width:auto;">
                </picture>
                <p class="logo-name"><a href="index.html">Keeva</a></p>
                            <!--  BURGER NAV -->

            </div>


            </div>

        <a class="burger-nav"></a>  
        </div>  

            <ul class="header-nav">
                <li><a id="home" href="#home-View">Home</a></li>
                <li><a id="about" href="#about-View">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a id="contact" href="#contact-View">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
    </header>
```

**Blog.html**

```
    <header class="main-header">
        <div class="header-container">
            <!-- logo wrapper -->
            <div class="logo-wrapper">

            <div id="logo-img-name">
                <picture>
<!--                    <source class="logo-img" media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img/mobile/mobile-logo.jpg">
 --><!--                  <source media="(min-width: 465px)" srcset="img_white_flower.jpg">
 -->                  <img class="logo-img" src="img/desktop/images/logo.png" alt="Flowers" style="width:auto;">
                </picture>
                <p class="logo-name"><a href="index.html">Keeva</a></p>
                            <!--  BURGER NAV -->

            </div>


            </div>

        <a class="burger-nav"></a>  
        </div>  

            <ul class="header-nav">
                <li><a id="home" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a id="about" href="#about-View">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a id="contact" href="#contact-View">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
    </header>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // add a click listener to each <a> tags
    setBindings();

    // burger nav
    $(".burger-nav").on("click", function() {
        $(".header-nav").toggleClass("open");   
    });

});

/* ONE PAGE NAVIGATION FUNCTION */
function setBindings() {
    $(".header-nav a").click(function(e) {
        // prevent anchor tags for working (?)
        e.preventDefault();
        var sectionID = e.currentTarget.id + "-View";

        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: $("#" + sectionID).offset().top
        }, 1000)
    })
}
```

Full index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>KEEVA APP</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--  extra -->
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:700" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>



    <header class="main-header">
        <div class="header-container">
            <!-- logo wrapper -->
            <div class="logo-wrapper">

            <div id="logo-img-name">
                <picture>
                    <source class="logo-img" media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img/mobile/mobile-logo.jpg">
<!--                  <source media="(min-width: 465px)" srcset="img_white_flower.jpg">
 -->                  <img class="logo-img" src="img_orange_flowers.jpg" alt="Flowers" style="width:auto;">
                </picture>
                <p class="logo-name"><a href="index.html">Keeva</a></p>
                            <!--  BURGER NAV -->

            </div>


            </div>

        <a class="burger-nav"></a>  
        </div>  

            <ul class="header-nav">
                <li><a id="home" href="#home-View">Home</a></li>
                <li><a id="about" href="#about-View">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a id="contact" href="#contact-View">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
    </header>
    <div class="main-content">
        <div id="home-View" class="sec-1">
        <div class="flex-desktop-sec-1">
            <div class="col-1">
                <h1>Introducing 'Keeva' world's smartest assistant.</h1>
                <h2>Keeva smartphone app helps you organize your work schedule, meetings, project deadlines and much more.</h2> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
            <!-- Download Buttons -->
                <div class="download-wrap">
                <!--  playstore icon -->
                    <picture>
                  <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img/mobile/mobile-playstore.png">
                              <source media="(min-width: 465px)" srcset="img_white_flower.jpg">
                              <img class="download-btns" src="img_orange_flowers.jpg" alt="Flowers" style="width:auto;">
                </picture>
                <!--  appstore icon -->
                    <picture>
                  <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img/mobile/mobile-appstore.png">
                              <!-- <source media="(min-width: 465px)" srcset="img/tablet/tablet-hero-iphone.jpg"> -->
                              <img class="download-btns" src="img_orange_flowers.jpg" alt="Flowers" style="width:auto;">
                </picture>
                </div>  
                </div>
            </div>
                    <!-- iphone 1 image wrap -->
                <div class="hero-img">
                <!--  iphone image -->
                    <picture>
<!--                                        <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img/desktop/images/home_03.jpg">
 -->                        <img class="phone-img" src="img/desktop/images/home_03.jpg" alt="Flowers">
                    </picture>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sec-2">
            <h3>Say hi to Keeva.</h3>
            <h4>World’s most smartest personal assistant in your procket.</h4>

            <!-- ipad 1 image -->
            <picture id="sec-2-picure">
                <!-- <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img/mobile/mobile-ipad.jpg"> -->
                          <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img/desktop/images/home_07.jpg">
                <img class="phone-img" src="img_orange_flowers.jpg" alt="Flowers" style="width:60%">
            </picture>          

        </div>
        <div class="sec-3">
                <!-- iphone image  -->
            <div class="sec-3-flex">
            <!-- Iphone 1 image -->
                <picture id="iphone-sec-3">
<!--                              <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img/desktop/images/home_11.jpg">
 -->                    <img  id="iphone-2-img" src="img/desktop/images/home_11.jpg" alt="Flowers">
                </picture>
                <div class="sales-copy-wrap">
                    <h3>Get organized with events, tasks and notes.</h3>
                    <p class="sales-copy">Now more then ever it is critical for smart professionals to stay up to date with important deadlines.</p>
                </div>              
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="sec-4">
                <!-- iphone image  -->
            <div class="sales-copy-wrap">
                <h3>Collaborate easily with your team members.</h3>
                <p class="sales-copy">We understand communication is key to successful execution of your projects. Stay connected and updated.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="image-wrapper">
                <picture id="iphone-sec-4">
<!--                              <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img/desktop/images/home_14.jpg">
 -->                    <img id="iphone-3-img" src="img/desktop/images/home_14.jpg" alt="Flowers">
                </picture>              
            </div>
        </div>
        <div  id="about-View" class="bg-1-wrapper">
        <!-- Bg work banner -->
            <picture>
                <img  id="bg-work-img" src="img/desktop/home1.jpg" alt="Flowers" style="width:100%">
            </picture>                  
        </div>

        <div  class="sec-5">

            <h3 class="about-title"> MEET OUR TEAM </h3>

            <div class="about-us-section">

                <div class="about-wrapper">

                <div class="about-flex">
                    <picture>
                        <img class="founder-img" src="img/desktop/images/home_24.jpg" alt="Flowers">
                    </picture>              

                    <picture>
                        <img class="founder-img" src="img/desktop/images/home_24.jpg" alt="Flowers">
                    </picture>  
                </div>

                <div class="founder-names-wrap">
                    <h5> John M. </h5>

                    <h5> Tyson P. </h5>             
                </div>

            </div>  

                <div class="about-content">
                    <div class="section-para">
                        <p id="founder-headline">The Founders</p>           
                        <p class="sales-copy">In the summer of 2012 Mike and Tyson developed the initial concept of Keeva. After researching the market for a solution to their problem they decided to design and build the product from scratch. </p> </br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="section-para"> 
                        <p id="founder-headline"> Our Mission </p>
                        <p class="sales-copy">Keeva’s objective is to revolutionize the digital market by enabling young professionals to optmize their work-life.</p>              
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>          
        </div>
 <!--  footer  -->
<footer>
     <div class="box green">
                <div class="about-footer">
                <h3 class="about-us-title">ABOUT US</h3>
                <article class="about-article">
                    Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simp. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simp
                </article>           
            </div>

  </div>
  <div class="box red">
                <div class="social-footer">
                <h3 class="connect-us-title">Connect With Us</h3>
                <div class="social-flex">
                    <img class="social-icon" src="img/desktop/images/twitter.jpg">                   
                    <img class="social-icon" src="img/desktop/images/insta.jpg">                     
                    <img class="social-icon" src="img/desktop/images/fb.jpg">

                </div>  
                            <p id="footer-copyright-text"> KEEVA INC © 2017 | Designed by Radian3 </p>

            </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box orange">
     <div class="location-footer">
                                <h3 class="contact-us-title"> Our Location</h3>
                <div class="location-content-wrap">
                    <div class="location-image-wrap">
                        <img class="maps-icon" src="img/desktop/images/home_31.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="address-footer">
                        <img class="location-icon" src="img/desktop/images/home_35.jpg">
                        <p> 25/153 Queens St, Avenue, Brisbane, QLD, 4000</p>                       
                        <p> Email: support@keeva.com</p>                        
                    </div>          
                </div>           
            </div>
  </div>

        </footer>


        <!--  JQuery -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Script -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your javascript - specifically here:

```
    // prevent anchor tags for working (?)
    e.preventDefault();
```

Is preventing the page changing. This looks like you are adapting a "one page" website.

Change that section to:

```
$(".header-nav a.scrollLink").click(function(e) {
    // prevent anchor tags for working (?)
    e.preventDefault();
    var sectionID = e.currentTarget.id + "-View";
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $("#" + sectionID).offset().top
    }, 1000)
})
```

...and put the calss `scrollLink` on the links you DO want to smooth scroll down the page

Comment: Yes, works perfect. But Part 2 issue still remains - on the blog.html when I click about page it should go to the index.html then #about-View div. any ideas?

Comment: You need to change the link to: <a id="about" href="index.html#about-View">About</a> - This instructs the browser to go TO the index.html page THEN to the about-View ID

Comment: Yes, I've tried at @mayersdesign it points to the right path but doesn't go when I click.

Comment: I have this essentially:     <li><a id="about" class="scrollLink" href="index.html#about-View">About</a> </li>

Comment: Yes that's right, although it won't scroll when it gets to the index page (which would probably be annoying anyway) - it will jump directly to the "about" section.